# How to sum of value in gridview select data from database in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I work in asp.net and i have one grid view in which i find out pf and ESI value from Basic Salary and I want proper solution of sum of total PF and total ESI in gridview footer in Repues So please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to write the code in RowDataBound Event of gridview.

i am posting a sample code for your reference try it yourself

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
   {
      Label lblPrice = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblPrice");
      Label lblUnitsInStock = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblUnitsInStock");

      decimal price = Decimal.Parse(lblPrice.Text);
      decimal stock = Decimal.Parse(lblUnitsInStock.Text);

      totalPrice += price;
      totalStock += stock;

      totalItems += 1;
   }

   if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
   {
      Label lblTotalPrice = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblTotalPrice");
      Label lblTotalUnitsInStock = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblTotalUnitsInStock");

      lblTotalPrice.Text = totalPrice.ToString();
      lblTotalUnitsInStock.Text = totalStock.ToString();

      lblAveragePrice.Text = (totalPrice / totalItems).ToString("F");
   }
}
```

check this too http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972833.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
  you can implement the code in RowDataBound Event of GridView
```

http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/02/how-to-display-sum-of-columns-total-in.html

http://aspdotnetsubhash.blogspot.in/

http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1676759

Please check your solution given url

May be you find your solution..............